# Mysterious magnifying glass in Facebook Feed Dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods

I installed Facebook iOS SDK via CocoaPods with Podfile

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
```

Screenshot is as follow:

[image: Weird magnifying glass]

A magnifying glass appears on the top right corner in Simulator, when I use the following code (in a button's `IBAction`) to attempt to share a message to Facebook (I follow the tutorial at [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)):

```
FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
params.name = @"Google";
params.caption = @"Google is Great";
params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png"];
params.description = @"Google is a good search engine";

if([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]) {
    // Present share dialog (requires Facebook App v6.0+ installed)
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                     name:params.name
                                  caption:params.caption
                              description:params.description
                                  picture:params.picture
                              clientState:nil
                                  handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
         if(error) {
             NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
         } else {
             NSLog(@"result %@", results);
         }
     }];
} else {
    // Present feed dialog
    NSMutableDictionary *params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Google", @"name",
                                   @"Google is Great", @"caption",
                                   @"Google is a good search engine", @"description",
                                   @"http://www.google.com", @"link",
                                   @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                                   nil];

    [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           parameters:params1
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                  if (error) {
                                                      // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                      // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                      NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                                                  } else {
                                                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                          // User cancelled.
                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                          NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                          if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                              // User cancelled.
                                                              NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                          } else {
                                                              // User clicked the Share button
                                                              NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                              NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }];
}
```

And this at the end of the class, before `@end`:

```
// A function for parsing URL parameters returned by the Feed Dialog.
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *val =
        [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        params[kv[0]] = val;
    }
    return params;
}
```

Feed dialog is used because the Simulator does not have Facebook App v6.0+

The magnifying glass blocks the Share button completely. How can I remove it?

Note: The version installed is v3.13.0 (at the moment of writing, the official latest version is 3.13.1).

Note: iOS used are 6.0, 7.0, 7.1.

Comment: This is also happening for a very small proportion of our live users on iOS  and Android. Our app is written with Adobe AIR and uses the Fresh Planet ANE for Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by Facebook in server side. The magnifier has been removed.

No need to update Facebook SDK.